# Eloquent query to not repeat data on an association

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an internal acknowledgment system, where workers can "thank" a coworker.

The table "thank" has two "user" relation, a one-to-one on a "user_from_id" field for the userFrom association, and a many-to-many on a pivot-table, called "thank_user" for the userTo association.

I need to query all the N "Thanks" which the UserFrom is not on the userTo relation, exclusive on the result set. In other words, the user cannot repeat within the result, be on the userFrom or the userTo association.

I came up with the following SQL, but I found it a dirty hack. How can I translate it to a Eloquent query?

```
create table tmp as select * from (
    select thanks.id, thanks.user_from_id, thank_user.user_id, thanks.created_at from thanks
    inner join thank_user on thank_user.thank_id=thanks.id
    group by user_from_id) 
t
group by user_id;

select * from tmp
    where user_from_id not in (select user_id from tmp)
    and created_at between '2014-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
    order by rand()
    limit 10;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you overcomplicate it. Why not just a `thank` table with `user_from_id` and `user_to_id` both as integers. Is there any particular reason you put the *from* data in a seperate table?

Comment: Yes, the usersTo is a 1:N relation, a user can thank more than one coworker on the same "thank", eg. a team.

Comment: Bug: `GROUP BY` without specifying all the non-aggregate values can lead to random values for each column -- independently.

Comment: @zeeto you already have more than one `user_to_id` across your table. You can replicate your `user_from_id` as well, it'll be fine. Your SQLs will be way easier to write. I'm posting it as answer in a few minutes. Also, I didn't get what you want to query. Could you explain that any more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the whole *thanking* stuff on a single table. Because *thanking* is already a pivot data. It binds a user to another one via an action which is *thanking* in your situation.

**Also,** can you be more clear about the SQL result you want to get? Explain as a real world result like "I want to get how many people thanked only one person." and not like "I want to get all the rows where count of from_id is one."

```
------------------------
| Table: thanks        |
------------------------
| id | from_id | to_id |
------------------------
|  1 |       1 |     1 |
|  2 |       1 |     2 |
|  3 |       1 |     3 |
|  6 |       2 |     1 |
|  7 |       2 |     2 |
------------------------
```

All the thanks a user has given (replace `*` with `COUNT(id)` to have the count of thanks):

```
SELECT * FROM thanks WHERE from_id = {id}
```

All the thanks a user has taken (replace `*` with `COUNT(id)` to have the count of thanks):

```
SELECT * FROM thanks WHERE to_id = {id}
```

Whether a user thanked another user:

```
SELECT * FROM thanks WHERE from_id = {from_id} AND to_id = {to_id}
```